# Overloading of Operators Unresolved External Error LNK1120,LNK2019

Tags: c++

I have been trying to make a class of complex numbers work and just recently managed to make my 2 friend function definitions compile without errors
Now I'm trying to test the overloaded operators by making 3 complex class objects in the (this is my main.cpp file)ExtraCredit.cpp file

```
    complex x(3.2);
    complex y(3.4, 4.1);
    complex z;

    z = x + y;

    cout << z;
```

The program worked up to `z = x + y` correctly but when I added

```
cout << z;
```

The output should be `6.2 + 4.1bi`

But instead I get these 2 errors

```
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals 

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >&_cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>>&,class complex)"(??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@Vcomplex@@@Z)referenced n function_main
```

In my ExtraCredit.cpp file I have

```
#include "stdafx.h" // This is VSO
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

using namespace std;
```

in the top of complex.h

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#include <iostream>
```

at the end of complex.h

```
#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

in the top of my complex.cpp file I have

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "complex.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

this is the overload prototype of the << operator in complex.h

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c);
```

this is the implementation/definition in complex.cpp

```
 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, complex const& c) {
    return out << c.getReal() << "+" << c.getImag() << "i";
}
```

Comment: Are you linking with complex.cpp?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be complex.h that auto links to complex.cpp? I'm linking to complex.h in the ExtraCredit.cpp file and the overload of the + operator when used doesn't give errors but the cout << does give the error when used

Comment: Linking is a separate step from compiling. What you're thinking of is including (with the `#include` directive). But since you're using VS I think it's linking all of your cpp files anyway. Danh's answer seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration is not the same with your definition:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, complex const& c) {
    return out << c.getReal() << "+" << c.getImag() << "i";
}
```

You need to change your declaration to

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const complex &c);
```

Comment: I just deleted the const& from the definition(is that bad practice? ) it also worked that way

Comment: Yeah, it will work too. However, it isn't a good practice since you will pass that complex object by value, it means the function call will create a temporary copy object, hence, increases the performance cost (which is not necessary). Which doesn't make sense here